# SharePoint Online user/group field error: The user does not exist or is not unique

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, csom, person-or-group

This error has been noticed in 2 ways in the past, when on SharePoint Online.

1. When a user types in a name into the person field on a SharePoint form, this error appears when the user tries to save the form.

   **Things i noticed:** 
   -For some reason, the name is duplicated on the person field suggestion. 
   -If the second option of the duplicate is selected, it works fine. Only the first one is a problem, even though they are both exactly the same if you hover over them and view the account details (username, email, etc)
2. Sometimes, when a function/CSOM API/REST call, etc. writes a username into the person field, it throws the same error.

   **Things i noticed:**
   -This time there is no duplicates of that username 
   -This works fine if you manually add in the same username it previously threw an error with 
   -This is not a common occurrence, meaning it only returns this error with certain users 
   -There has been no changes to the user account in the last few months for it to be invalid.

Please note that i have not experienced this first hand, i noticed this when assisting a support specialist who was investigating the issue at the time. Sorry for not having anymore information, logs or even the CSOM script that was used. If anyone has had similar experiences, please let me know of the resolution, thanks!